# Problen while creating ID2D1RenderTerget

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

I`m new to Direct2d, and trying to make function that creates render target (something like part of eigne), but i get problem with this. When i create render target in main it works, but not outside.
Function that i try to create:

```
{
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

    D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(
        rc.right - rc.left,
        rc.bottom - rc.top
    );

    // Create a Direct2D render target.
        factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
        D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
        D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hwnd, size),
        &rendertarget);

}
```

Compiling errors:

> Error (active) E0304   no instance of overloaded function "ID2D1Factory::CreateHwndRenderTarget" matches the argument list
>
> Error  C2664   'HRESULT ID2D1Factory::CreateHwndRenderTarget(const D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES &,const D2D1_HWND_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES &,ID2D1HwndRenderTarget **)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES' to 'const D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES *'

Full code:

```
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <d2d1_1helper.h>
#include <wincodec.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"d2d1.lib")
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

ID2D1Factory* factory;
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* rendertarget;

void test(ID2D1Factory* factory,ID2D1RenderTarget* rendertarget, HWND hwnd)
{
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

    D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(
        rc.right - rc.left,
        rc.bottom - rc.top
    );

    // Create a Direct2D render target.
        factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
        D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
        D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hwnd, size),
        &rendertarget);

}
int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(wc));
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"class";

    RegisterClass(&wc);
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(
        L"class",
        L"Direct2D init",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 600, 600,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    RECT clrc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &clrc);
    D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE::D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &factory);
    HRESULT hr = factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
        D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(
            hwnd, D2D1::SizeU(clrc.right - clrc.left, clrc.bottom - clrc.top))
        ,&rendertarget);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);

    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        rendertarget->BeginDraw();
        rendertarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));
        rendertarget->EndDraw();
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't match your code to the error message you say you are getting, it makes no sense to me. Perhaps you should post a complete program with this error. Please remove any irrelevant code before posting a complete program.

Comment: Use [mre] as inspiration while fulfilling John's request.

Comment: make sure `rendertarget` is a `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget*`

Comment: @sim: That's not a requirement. The requirement is, that the expression `&rendertarget` needs to be of type `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget**`, or be implicitly convertible to that type.

Comment: @IInspectable - of course but I was considering 1) the obvious lack of OP's competence (no offense) and 2) the fact Direct2D doesn't define any derivate of ID2D1HwndRenderTarget

Comment: @sim: Direct2D is exposed as COM. With the question being tagged [tag:c++] it's hard to argue, that the code weren't using something like [_com_ptr_t](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-class) in place of a raw pointer. This wasn't nitpicking, but addressing a very common implementation choice.

Comment: @john i added full code

Comment: @sim: With that your statement boils down to: *"Make sure `rendertarget` is of type `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` or a `_com_ptr_t` class template instantiation, but **it must not be a [`CComPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptr-class) class template instantiation**."* That statement is provably wrong, even under the undue restriction of requiring an object-oriented programming paradigm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, your must declare `renderTarget` as `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget*` because the [CreateHwndRenderTarget method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1factory-createhwndrendertarget(constd2d1_render_target_properties__constd2d1_hwnd_render_target_properties__id2d1hwndrendertarget)) expects this type, so just change your `test` code declaration like this for example:

```
void test(ID2D1Factory* factory, ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* rendertarget, HWND hwnd)
```